# SQL: сумма положительных и отрицательных чисел столбца

Tags: oracle, select, sql

Требуется написать запрос, возвращающий сумму положительных и отрицательных чисел столбца как минимум 5-ю разными способами.
Я смог придумать только один:

```
select sum(num) from table where num<=0 UNION select sum(num) from table where num>0
```

Другие способы не должны содержать UNION.

Answer (score 4):

```
select sum(case when num<=0 then num else 0 end), sum(case when num<=0 then 0 else num end) from table

select sum(num) from table group by sign(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT -((SUM(ABS(n))) - SUM(n))/2 AS neg_sum, ((SUM(ABS(n))) + SUM(n))/2 AS pos_sum FROM number;
```

Не знаком с синтаксисом Oracle, но, наверно, там можно ввести какие-то временные переменные для замены одинаковых выражений.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(decode(sign(num),1,num,0)), sum(decode(sign(num),-1,num,0));
```